# Maya loading custom attributes from file

Tags: maya

I am trying to use Maya as my level creator. I have created some custom attributes for objects to use, and saved them out (into a .mel file). However, when I try to apply this preset to an object, the only values it uses are values intrinsic to Maya, such as traslation and scale.

The documentation on this subject is very sparse and there doesn't seem to be much information on this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.